# Javascript calculation (Products sum without Vat)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Hello I have a problem with some calculation in javascript(see image)

[image]

The cell that is with red border calculate product  price sum with vat.
What im trying to do but didnt success is to calculate product price sum WITHOUT VAT(the cell with red broder should be 2000 not 2200)

Here is the code that im using,

```
        var row_no = (new Date).getTime();
        var newTr = $('<tr id="row_' + row_no + '" class="row_' + item_id + '" data-item-id="' + item_id + '"></tr>');
        tr_html = '<td><input name="product_id[]" type="hidden" class="rid" value="' + product_id + '"><input name="product[]" type="hidden" class="rcode" value="' + item_code + '"><input name="product_name[]" type="hidden" class="rname" value="' + item_name + '"><input name="product_option[]" type="hidden" class="roption" value="' + item_option + '"><input name="part_no[]" type="hidden" class="rpart_no" value="' + item_supplier_part_no + '"><span class="sname" id="name_' + row_no + '">' + item_code +' - '+ item_name +(sel_opt != '' ? ' ('+sel_opt+')' : '')+' <span class="label label-default">'+item_supplier_part_no+'</span></span> <i class="pull-right fa fa-edit tip edit" id="' + row_no + '" data-item="' + item_id + '" title="Edit" style="cursor:pointer;"></i></td>';
        if (site.settings.product_expiry == 1) {
            tr_html += '<td><input class="form-control date rexpiry" name="expiry[]" type="text" value="' + item_expiry + '" data-id="' + row_no + '" data-item="' + item_id + '" id="expiry_' + row_no + '"></td>';
        }
        tr_html += '<td class="text-right"><input class="form-control input-sm text-right rcost" name="net_cost[]" type="hidden" id="cost_' + row_no + '" value="' + item_cost + '"><input class="rucost" name="unit_cost[]" type="hidden" value="' + unit_cost + '"><input class="realucost" name="real_unit_cost[]" type="hidden" value="' + item.row.real_unit_cost + '"><span class="text-right scost" id="scost_' + row_no + '">' + formatMoney(item_cost) + '</span></td>';
        tr_html += '<td><input name="quantity_balance[]" type="hidden" class="rbqty" value="' + item_bqty + '"><input class="form-control text-center rquantity" name="quantity[]" type="text" tabindex="'+((site.settings.set_focus == 1) ? an : (an+1))+'" value="' + formatQuantity2(item_qty) + '" data-id="' + row_no + '" data-item="' + item_id + '" id="quantity_' + row_no + '" onClick="this.select();"><input name="product_unit[]" type="hidden" class="runit" value="' + product_unit + '"><input name="product_base_quantity[]" type="hidden" class="rbase_quantity" value="' + base_quantity + '"></td>';
        if (po_edit) {
            tr_html += '<td class="rec_con"><input name="ordered_quantity[]" type="hidden" class="oqty" value="' + item_oqty + '"><input class="form-control text-center received" name="received[]" type="text" value="' + formatDecimal(unit_qty_received) + '" data-id="' + row_no + '" data-item="' + item_id + '" id="received_' + row_no + '" onClick="this.select();"><input name="received_base_quantity[]" type="hidden" class="rrbase_quantity" value="' + qty_received + '"></td>';
        }
        if (site.settings.product_discount == 1) {
            tr_html += '<td class="text-right"><input class="form-control input-sm rdiscount" name="product_discount[]" type="hidden" id="discount_' + row_no + '" value="' + item_ds + '"><span class="text-right sdiscount text-danger" id="sdiscount_' + row_no + '">' + formatMoney(0 - (item_discount * item_qty)) + '</span></td>';
        }
        tr_html += '<td class="text-right"><span class="text-right ssubtotal" id="subtotal_' + row_no + '">' + formatMoney((parseFloat(item_cost) * parseFloat(item_qty))) + '</span></td>';
        if (site.settings.tax1 == 1) {
            tr_html += '<td class="text-right"><input class="form-control input-sm text-right rproduct_tax" name="product_tax[]" type="hidden" id="product_tax_' + row_no + '" value="' + pr_tax.id + '"><span class="text-right sproduct_tax" id="sproduct_tax_' + row_no + '">' + (pr_tax_rate ? '(' + pr_tax_rate + ')' : '') + ' ' + formatMoney(pr_tax_val * item_qty) + '</span></td>';
        }

        tr_html += '<td class="text-right"><span class="text-right ssubtotal" id="subtotal_' + row_no + '">' + formatMoney(((parseFloat(item_cost) + parseFloat(pr_tax_val)) * parseFloat(item_qty))) + '</span></td>';
        tr_html += '<td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-times tip podel" id="' + row_no + '" title="Remove" style="cursor:pointer;"></i></td>';
        newTr.html(tr_html);
        newTr.prependTo("#poTable");
        total += formatDecimal(((parseFloat(item_cost) + parseFloat(pr_tax_val)) * parseFloat(item_qty)), 4);
        count += parseFloat(item_qty);
        an++;
        if(!belong)
            $('#row_' + row_no).addClass('warning');
    });

    var col = 2;
    if (site.settings.product_expiry == 1) { col++; }
    var tfoot = '<tr id="tfoot" class="tfoot active"><th colspan="'+col+'">Total</th><th class="text-center">' + formatQty(parseFloat(count) - 1) + '</th>';
    if (po_edit) {
        tfoot += '<th class="rec_con"></th>';
    }
    if (site.settings.product_discount == 1) {
        tfoot += '<th class="text-right">'+formatMoney(product_discount)+'</th>';
    }
    tfoot += '<th class="text-right">'+formatMoney(total)+'</th>';
    if (site.settings.tax1 == 1) {
        tfoot += '<th class="text-right">'+formatMoney(product_tax)+'</th>';
    }
    tfoot += '<th class="text-right">'+formatMoney(total)+'</th><th class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50);"></i></th></tr>';
    $('#poTable tfoot').html(tfoot);
```

Comment: Well as this line `total += formatDecimal(((parseFloat(item_cost) + parseFloat(pr_tax_val)) * parseFloat(item_qty)), 4);` adds Tax into the total and thats the varibale you are using in that column, it sort of explains it

Comment: yes i know is for one result for grand total.all i needed was another total without vat.the problem is that i didnt add another var.thatnk you for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the total which you display right here:

```
total += formatDecimal(((parseFloat(item_cost) + parseFloat(pr_tax_val)) * parseFloat(item_qty)), 4);
```

For you to display a price without vat you need another variable for it

```
var totalNoVAT = 0;
```

and in the loop:

```
totalNoVAT += formatDecimal((parseFloat(item_cost) * parseFloat(item_qty)), 4);
```

and finally display it by changing this:

```
tfoot += '<th class="text-right">'+formatMoney(total)+'</th>';
```

to this:

```
tfoot += '<th class="text-right">'+formatMoney(totalNoVAT)+'</th>';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!I tried this opsion but the result is 0. Maybe i did smth wrong with this : totalNoVAT += formatDecimal((parseFloat(item_cost) * parseFloat(item_qty)), 4); Where to put this code?

Comment: Put it under the total += formatDecimal(((parseFloat(item_cost) + parseFloat(pr_tax_val)) * parseFloat(item_qty)), 4);

Comment: And put the totalNoVAT = 0 on top of all

Comment: Thank you sir! All is correct now.I appreciate your help and god bless you.I dont want to disturb you but if you can help me with 2 more things?

Comment: Thank you. As you see in the image i can input the product quantity but i cannot input the product cost directly(third column in picture) .Can you help me with this issue?I want to do the same with product cost .the code is in the question.

Comment: <input class="form-control text-center rquantity" name="quantity[]" type="text" tabindex="'+((site.settings.set_focus == 1) ? an : (an+1))+'" value="' + formatQuantity2(item_qty) + '" data-id="' + row_no + '" data-item="' + item_id + '" id="quantity_' + row_no + '" onClick="this.select();"> This is the quantity text input, so if you want to add product cost the same kind of input you can use this as your guideline

Comment: It's in row 8 of the code you submitted in the question

Comment: tr_html += '<td><input class="form-control text-center rcost" name="net_cost[]" type="text" tabindex="'+ formatMoney(item_cost) +'" value="' + formatMoney(item_cost) + '" data-id="' + row_no + '" data-item="' + item_id + '" id="scost_' + row_no + '" onClick="this.select();"><input class="rucost" name="unit_cost[]" type="hidden" value="' + unit_cost + '"><input class="realucost" name="real_unit_cost[]" type="hidden" value="' + item.row.real_unit_cost + '"></td>';

Comment: I can enter the sum but after presing enter it doesnt reflect the price and and turns to its old price.Smth i miss?  the code is in upper comment

Comment: sir  comments doesnt allow so much code.if you can give me an email adress or smth or i can make another questions here and you can answer it?